# How to write HTML tags without string declaration in vanilla js

Tags: javascript

If you want to use an HTML element in vanilla JavaScript without using a function like `Document.createElement()`, you need to use it like this:

```js
const App = `<h1>Hello, world</h1>`;
```

But is there a way to do this in vanilla JavaScript, just HTML tags without a string declaration (signs like ``)? For example:

```js
const App = <h1>Hello, world</h1>;
```

Comment: Nope, you need JSX for that

Comment: Read this doc about JSX in React [Introducing JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way you can do this without a declaration (but you still can do this without a *string* declaration).
For that, you have to use JSX in Vanilla JS using this npm package:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsx-vanilla

This unlock more features like embedding dynamic expressions and values in between the HTML code.
For an example:

```
let x = 4;

const menu = (
  <ul>
    <li>{x-1}</li>
    <li>{x}</li>
    <li>{x+1}</li>
  </ul>
);

const node = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(menu);
```

Technically, JSX is neither string nor HTML.